# VBA to extract series name, X, and Y values from Excel Chart

Tags: vba, excel, charts

I was looking for help on extracting data from an excel chart.  Specifically, I need to pull **series names**, **X**, and **Y** values from all points on the chart. I started with the basic code from Excel but it is only giving me X values.

```
Sub GetChartValues()
Dim NumberOfRows As Integer
Dim X As Object
Counter = 2

' Calculate the number of rows of data.
NumberOfRows = UBound(ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Values)

Worksheets("ChartData").Cells(1, 1) = "X Values"

' Write x-axis values to worksheet.
With Worksheets("ChartData")
  .Range(.Cells(2, 1), _
  .Cells(NumberOfRows + 1, 1)) = _
  Application.Transpose(ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues)
End With

' Loop through all series in the chart and write their values to
' the worksheet.
For Each X In ActiveChart.SeriesCollection
  Worksheets("ChartData").Cells(1, Counter) = X.Name

  With Worksheets("ChartData")
     .Range(.Cells(2, Counter), _
     .Cells(NumberOfRows + 1, Counter)) = _
     Application.Transpose(X.Values)
  End With

  Counter = Counter + 1
Next

End Sub
```

I need to figure out how to make this work so I can create tables of the given values. I have also attached an image of the chart I am working on. Any help would really be appreciated!

[image: Chart Picture]

[image: Station Timetable Picture]

Answer (score 1):

give this a go, make sure your chart is selected before running the code:

```
Sub Getting_data()

   Dim iSrs As Long
   Dim cht As Chart
   Dim srs As Series
   Dim wkst As Worksheet

   If ActiveChart Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

   Set cht = ActiveChart
   Set wkst = Worksheets.Add
   For iSrs = 1 To cht.SeriesCollection.Count
       Set srs = cht.SeriesCollection(iSrs)
       On Error Resume Next
       wkst.Cells(1, 2 * iSrs).value = srs.Name
       wkst.Cells(2, 2 * iSrs - 1).Resize(srs.Points.Count).value = _
           WorksheetFunction.Transpose(srs.XValues)
       wkst.Cells(2, 2 * iSrs).Resize(srs.Points.Count).value = _
           WorksheetFunction.Transpose(srs.Values)
   Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Do you think that there is a way to automate the tables that this creates and change them into the train and station time tables that I posted a picture of? Basically, the series name is the "Train Identification", the Y-value corresponds to the station location in KM, each station has a specific location.  The X-Values represent at what time a train is at a particular station.

Comment: Without seeing the data that is produced after running the code it is difficult to advise, however it sounds entirely possible to do this. depending on the level of data manipulation required it could be done just with excel formulas; IF, VLOOKUP.... If the manipulation is more complicated you can most likely use VBA but It would be wise to start a different Sub to the one above for this :)

Comment: Ok thank you! I will try the built in functions for now and see if I can get it to work the way I need.

Comment: This worked perfectly the first time I used it, however, I cannot duplicate it.  I keep getting "Compile Error: Expected End Sub"